# Ajustar dados a modelo exponencial no R

Tags: r

Boa noite,

Tenho duas variáveis sobre crescimento em insetos:
y- medidas de largura da cabeça(0.5,0.8,0.10,0.12,0.16)
x- idade em que foram medidas (1,2,3,4,5)

Preciso verificar se esse crescimento se ajusta a um crescimento exponencial. Preciso dos valores da equação gerada, de p e de r^2, além de F (apesar que F acho que não é possível, é?).

Não achei como fazer isso no R.

Obrigada

Bruna

Comment: Já tentou fazer uma transformação logarítmica de y e rodar uma regressão linear com `lm()`?

Comment: o que é p, F é do teste F?

Answer (score 1):

Na sua pergunta falta algumas explicações, mas de forma básica dá para fazer assim no R:

```
x<- c(1,2,3,4,5)
y<- c(0.5,0.8,0.10,0.12,0.16)

cbind(x,y)
n<-length(x)

cbind(x,log(y),x*log(y),x^2)
cbind(sum(x),sum(log(y)),sum(x*log(y)),sum(x^2))
num = sum(x*log(y)) - sum(x)*sum(log(y))/n
denom = sum(x^2) - sum(x)^2/n
a=num/denom
b=sum(log(y))/n - a*sum(x)/n

A = exp(a)
B = exp(b)

plot(x,y,col="blue",pch=19)
curvaexp<-curve(B*exp(a*x), NULL,NULL, 5, add=T, col=2)

curvaexp

r2.lm = lm(y ~ curvaexp$y) 
r2<- summary(r2.lm)$r.squared #<--- Coeficiente de Determinaçao
var.test(y, curvaexp$y)# variancia F
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma resposta em ingles

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560849/exponential-regression-with-nls-in-r

basicamente, usa a proposta do @Bernardo (lm() no log(largura da cabeca) - isso te da uma solucao do problema linear. E use essa solucao como inicalizacao da resolucao do problema nao linear (a regressao exponencial) usando o nls.

Mas eu acho que o nls nao te da essas medidas que voce quer, p, r^2 etc. Quem da isso é a regressao linear. Mas a regressao linear nao esta em termos de tamanho de cabeca e sim em log do tamamnho da cabeca.

Qual é a diferenca da solucao apenas usando o log e o lm()  e usar o nls? A solucao usando o log apenas assume que a equacao é

y = a * exp(b * x)

que tirando o log dos 2 lados da

log y = a + b*x

Usando o nls, o modelo pode ser

y = a * exp(b * x) + c